# ID not getting set in subscriber.list for CreateRequest

Tags: marketing-cloud, webservices, soap

I m trying to add a subscriber to a list. Though I am setting the id for the mailing list, its not getting reflected in the list. whereas the other attribute status, which I am setting is getting printed.

Below is source code:

```
public String getResponse(MyInput input)    
{   
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    CreateRequest request = factory.createCreateRequest();
    List<APIObject> objects = request.getObjects();
    Subscriber subscriber = factory.createSubscriber();
    subscriber.setEmailAddress(input.getEmailId());
    subscriber.setSubscriberKey(input.getEmailId());
    subscriber.setStatus(SubscriberStatus.ACTIVE);

    List<SubscriberList> listOfSubscriberList = new ArrayList<SubscriberList>();
    for(int id: mailingListIds) {
        listOfSubscriberList.add(getSubscriberList(id));
    }
    subscriber.getLists().addAll(listOfSubscriberList);
    objects.add(subscriber);

    for(SubscriberList s : subscriber.getLists()){
        logger.debug("Mailing list after adding to subscriber: ID="+s.getID()+", Status="+s.getStatus().name());
    }

    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(webServiceMessageSender);
    CreateResponse response = (CreateResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(request);
    return response.getOverallStatus();
}

private SubscriberList getSubscriberList(Integer id) {
    SubscriberList subscriberList = new SubscriberList();
    subscriberList.setID(id);
    subscriberList.setStatus(SubscriberStatus.ACTIVE);
    return subscriberList;
}
```

Request getting printed:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns3:CreateRequest
            xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com"
            xmlns:ns3="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <ns3:Objects
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:Subscriber">
                <ns3:EmailAddress>test@aa.com</ns3:EmailAddress>
                <ns3:SubscriberKey>test@aa.com</ns3:SubscriberKey>
                <ns3:Status>Active</ns3:Status>
                <ns3:Lists>
                    <ns3:Status>Active</ns3:Status>
                </ns3:Lists>
            </ns3:Objects>
        </ns3:CreateRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Can you tell me what exactly is wrong in my code? I am setting the ID as well as status in the subsciber.lists but only the status is displayed.

Comment: I can't speak for your code, but the SOAP body above does not provide the ID of the list you want the subscriber added to. There's a handy page here in online docs that gives plenty of examples in various languages... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/adding_subscribers_to_a_list.htm

Comment: I am following the same code.

Comment: If I change the attribute name from "ID" to "id", it works fine. It doesn't generate tag only when attribute name is "ID". This issue is only happening on linux and not on windows. @AndrewMcLeod

Comment: Mate, I feel for you, I do. If Windows has an issue, it's for a different forum.